# How do I make power computation for testing differnce between two log normal means with R? 

Tags: r, mean, statistical-power, lognormal-distribution

I want to do power computation for testing differnce between two log normal means with R. Can you write using R code? 
best wishes...

Comment: The answer is "yes."  If you need more than that, please amplify your question.

Answer (score 3):

A simple method for any power calculation is to use simulations.  Simulate data that represents what you are trying to test (difference, sample size, etc.) and test for the difference and save the p-value, repeate a bunch of times.  The proportion of times that your saved p-values are less than your $\alpha$ is the estimated power.